# Can I get all Route Fulfillment messages in Dialogflow CX by python API?

Tags: python, dialogflow-cx

In my Dialogflow CX flow I have a Route which answers to some detected Intent.
And here I can type many variations to answer - in Fulfillement section "Agent says".
[image: Answer cases]

When I use it by API I got only **1 answer** (in `response.query_result.response_messages`), I think **randomly selected** from all cases.
But I want to get all of my cases and select by my own in my code. Is it possible, is there such a method?
For example, I want to prevent sending user the same answer many times in one dialog.

Comment: Or the best way - adding new dialog options (button Add dialog option on screenshot) in this section? They appear in response.query_result.response_messages.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you use [detectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#detectintentresponse) method from detectIntent method, you will have 1 user query to get all of the responses in a particular route page you set from the Dialogflow CX console.

Please be noted that in Dialogflow CX Fulfillment, only 1 response will be returned randomly per **Text** Dialogue Option (or **Agent says** section).
You can refer here for [Fulfillment Static responses](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#static).

If you want to return multiple text responses from the Fulfillment section, you will need to add multiple **Text** dialogue options:
[image: multiple text responses]

This will have 2 Agent Text Responses returned from the detectIntent method:[image: multiple text responses test]

You can then fetch the text responses as an array from the fulfillment [responseMessage](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/Fulfillment?hl=en#responsemessage) text object.